# TWebbrowser not working when proxy specified

Tags: delphi, proxy, delphi-xe, twebbrowser

With Windows XP I have edited the Internet Options and set proxy details, I open IE8 - it then asks for the proxy username/password and then it will work fine.

I then open my app with a TWebbrowser however ALL urls will fail to load, it just comes up with a default windows looking page saying the page failed to load.

Do you need to do anything special to make TWebbrowser work with proxies?

Delphi XE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have the "Silent" property set on your WebBrowser control. That blocks the dialog that prompts the user for credentials for the proxy server.

See also 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/04/side-effects-of-setting-the-silent-scripterrorssuppressed-property-for-web-browser-control.aspx